# Integrating custom method into LINQ to Entities query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a custom method that performs some calculation on a set of data:

```
 private int GetPercentages(int OriginalValue, int TotalValue)
        {
            var newValue = (int)Math.Round(((decimal)OriginalValue / (decimal)TotalValue) * 100);

            return newValue;
         }
```

I need to be able to run this method inside of a LINQ to Entities query:

```
var data = from SurveyResponseModel in db.SurveyResponseModels
                       group SurveyResponseModel by SurveyResponseModel.MemberId into resultCount
                       select new ResultsViewModel()
                       {
                           MemberId = resultCount.Key,
                           PatientFollowUpResult = db.SurveyResponseModels.Count(r => r.PatientFollowUp),
                           PatientFollowUpResultPct = GetPercentages(db.SurveyResponseModels.Count(r => r.PatientFollowUp),totalResponsesResult),
                           ChangeCodingPracticeResult = db.SurveyResponseModels.Count(r => r.ChangeCodingPractice),
  };
```

I need to run this on about 20 more lines inside of the query so just sticking it inline doesn't seem like a great option.  I understand that it needs to be converted into SQL syntax, but is there anything else like this that I can do?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a lambda expression that calculates the percentage like this:

```
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> calcPercentage =
    (OriginalValue, TotalValue) => (int)Math.Round(((decimal)OriginalValue / (decimal)TotalValue) * 100);
```

And use it like this:

```
var data = from SurveyResponseModel in db.SurveyResponseModels.ToExpandable()
           group SurveyResponseModel by SurveyResponseModel.MemberId into resultCount
           select new ResultsViewModel()
           {
               MemberId = resultCount.Key,
               PatientFollowUpResult = db.SurveyResponseModels.Count(r => r.PatientFollowUp),
               PatientFollowUpResultPct = calcPercentage.Invoke(db.SurveyResponseModels.Count(r => r.PatientFollowUp), totalResponsesResult),
               ChangeCodingPracticeResult = db.SurveyResponseModels.Count(r => r.ChangeCodingPractice),
           };
```

More info about calling functions in LINQ queries [here](http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx).

Comment: Hmm.. The expression is giving me an error "Delegate system.func does not take 2 parameters"

Comment: @user547794 I corrected the answer. The expression type should be `Func<int, int, int>` which takes 2 `int` parameters and returns an `int`.

Comment: Looks like the expression is working, but I'm getting a "has some invalid arguments" on "calcPercentage.Invoke(db.SurveyResponseModels.Count(r => r.PatientFollowUp), totalResponsesResult)"

Comment: @user547794 What is the type of `totalResponsesResult`? It should be `int`. If it is not you need to cast it to `int` or change the expression delegate to accept some other type.

Comment: totalResponseResult is indeed an int.  When I try to build I get "Error 9 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression" and Error 10 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[]'"