# How to rewrite a method so that it could be executed in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following helper method:

```
public static double CalculateKilosPerMeter(double diameter, double thickness)
{
    return (diameter - thickness) * thickness * Math.PI * 0.008;
}
```

I use it when creating an instance of a Model class for a specific entity.

```
return pt => new ViewablePipeTypeModel()
{
    Id = pt.Id,
    KilosPerMeter = Logic.CalculateKilosPerMeter(pt.Diameter, pt.Thickness)
};
```

When I execute the code above, I get the following exception:

```
 LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double CalculateKilosPerMeter(Double, Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression
```

So, I suppose this is because EF requires an ExpressionFunc.

**How can I convert my method so it runs under LINQ to Entities?**

Comment: Have you tried expanding it inline? Ie putting the calculation directly in the LINQ expression instead of invoking the helper method?

Comment: Yes, that works, but I need to do the same calculation more than once that's why I wanted to separate it in a method.

Comment: @Tormod has right, the problem is EF doesn't know how to translate your method to an sql expression, so you could do that calculus inline, otherwise,if you want to call a custom method in the `Select`, then you need to call the `AsEnumerable` method before, this way you are going to work wiht Linq to Object, wich support that action.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042668/given-linq-to-entities-does-not-support-custom-methods-how-do-you-stay-dry

Comment: @octavioccl yeap, I'm aware of that, but I was wondering if there's way I can convert this to a Expression<Func<PipeType, double>> and then invoke this thing somehow.

Comment: @Yulian, yes, it is possible, follow the link i provided in previous comment ;)

Comment: @MaciejLos I've read it. I created the method appropriately but then I don't know how to use it interchangeably, according to the code that I provided above. Please, give me some more clues

Comment: Another useful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164655/integrating-custom-method-into-linq-to-entities-query

Comment: I get the same error that user547794 described in his/her comment in the question you posted.

Comment: @Yulian, i posted an answer. Please, check it. More: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867100/workarounds-for-using-custom-methods-extension-methods-in-linq-to-entities

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain anonymous type records first with all the data needed, and then use `AsEnumerable()` to use regular LINQ to Objects.

```
var objs = ... pt => new
{
    Id = pt.Id,
    Diam = pt.Diameter,
    Thick = pt.Thickness
};

var res = objs.AsEnumerable().Select(p => new ViewablePipeTypeModel()
{
    Id = p.Id,
    KilosPerMeter = Logic.CalculateKilosPerMeter(p.Diam, p.Thick)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a compiled query and move your logic into that.  It will produce a function that you can use within your queries as if it was a regular function.

```
Func<MyDataContext, double, double, double> calculateKilosPerMeter =
    CompiledQuery.Compile((MyDataContext dc, double diameter, double thickness) =>
        (diameter - thickness) * thickness * Math.PI * 0.008
    );
var query =
    from pt in dc.PipeTypes
    where ...
    select new ViewablePipeTypeModel()
    {
        Id = pt.Id,
        KilosPerMeter = calculateKilosPerMeter(dc, pt.Diameter, pt.Thickness),
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

**Method:**

```
public Expression<Func<PipeType, double>> KilosPerMeter
{
    return f=>(f.diameter - f.thickness) * f.thickness * Math.PI * 0.008;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public void DoSomething()
{
  using(var vptm = new ViewablePipeTypeModel())
  {
      var qry = from pt in vptm
          select new
          {
            Id = pt.Id,
            KpM = pt.KilosPerMeter()
          };
  }
}
```

Note: i have no chance to test it.

I'd suggest to read this article: [Calling Functions in LINQ to Entities Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456828%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)